# How to "fread" a list of files with a different number of columns?

Tags: r, function, data.table, fread

Usually, I am led to read lists of files which all have the same format, the same number of columns.
My function looks like :

```
fun.read <- function(files) {
  read <- function(filename){
    DT <- data.table::fread(filename, header = FALSE, sep = ";", select = 1:7, col.names = c(...))
  }
  lst <- lapply(files, read)
}
```

It works fine.

But now, I have to do the same, assuming my files doesn't have the same number of columns.
The way I do this is, for example, something like :

```
fun.read <- function(files) {
  read <- function(filename){
    if (max(count.fields(filename, sep = ";")) == 7) {
      DT <- data.table::fread(filename, header = FALSE, sep = ";", select = 1:7, col.names = c(...))
    } else if (max(count.fields(filename, sep = ";")) == 8){
      DT <- data.table::fread(filename, header = FALSE, sep = ";", select = 1:8, col.names = c(...))
    }
  }
  lst <- lapply(files, read)
}
```

It seems to work fine too, but I'm wondering if there is not a more efficient / elegant way to do this ?

I looked towards the `fill = TRUE` option, without success...

Many thanks !!

Comment: Why do you have specify the `select = 1:7`.  If you don't specify, then it will read all the columns.  and you don't need any if/else

Comment: indeed. `lapply(files, fread)` seems the logical answer here.

Comment: @akrun I think because of the col.names. Sometimes it is a vector of length 7, sometimes of length 8.

Comment: @Discus23 You just need the code that Oliver specified.  The `sep` is not needed as it will be automatically detected in fread

Comment: I understood that to specify ```sep``` improve performance ? Wrong ?

Comment: I honestly haven't tested it. But from the help file it states that it uses the first couple of rows to detect the seperator (if i remember right). Unless you dataset is very big, this is likely only a fraction of a fraction of the time spent.

Comment: Even if you dataset is small** it is likely only a fraction of a fraction**

Comment: What happens when you do `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread),fill=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

In case it could be helpfull to someone, here is how I lightened my script :
Including the `if` in the `col.names()`

```
x <- max(count.fields(filename, sep = ";"))
DT <- data.table::fread(filename, header = FALSE, sep = ";", col.names = c("...", "...", "...", if(x>3)"..."))
```

Thanks.